# How do I extract single record from a large CSV using csvtojson

Tags: node.js, csvtojson

I'm trying to read only the first record of a large CSV using [csvtojson](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson)
I've to use this library, as it will be used later to extract all the records, and I need consistency in data format between the 2 fetches.

My current code looks like this:

```
const sampleRecord = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  csv({
    trim: true,
    checkType: true,
    ignoreEmpty: true,
    maxRowLength: 65535
  })
  .fromFile(filePath)
  .subscribe(resolve, reject);
});

console.log('res', sampleRecord);
return sampleRecord;
```

Now while the sampleRecord is getting printed alright on console, I'm getting an empty object returned by the line below. What could be the reason? Also, how do I stop processing after extracting the first record?

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first record, then read the first 2 lines of the CSV and provide that string as an input to `csvtojson`.

Refer:

[Stream and read the first two lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45556848/515774)

[Convert csv string to csv row](https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson#from-csv-string-to-csv-row)

For the empty object that is being returned, probably you are not awaiting for the promise to return from where this method is being called.

Comment: Actually I'm awaiting the promise, as you can see on the first line itself. The record is getting console logged as well, but not being returned. In any case, I think if there was such an issue then the returned value would be null or undefined, but not an empty object.